# Multi-threading issue + DataReady already open

Tags: winforms, multithreading, ado.net, datareader

We are developing a WinForms application in my company.
We are facing a threading issue.

A thread TH is started in the runtime beginning.
TH reads regularly a record from a table TB.
A DataTable is used for retrieving the record.
The DataTable is filled by a SqlDataAdapter.
The DataTable is disposed as soon as an object is created modeling the retrieved record.

A DataGridView in a Form could be filled with data from TB during the runtime.
The DataGridView must be filled on the main thread that is the thread where user controls are created.
But an exception is thrown when filling a DataTable.
The exception message adverts that a DataReader is already open on the Command used to retrieve records from TB.

I have tried without success to surround a statement executed on TH in a lock block.
I am not used to threading programmation so I do not know what I can do to prevent the exception.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post code to explain the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have got useful information from this web page : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.80).aspx

The web page contains this information :

> Note that while a DataReader is open, the Connection is in use
>   exclusively by that DataReader. You cannot execute any commands for
>   the Connection, including creating another DataReader, until the
>   original DataReader is closed.

In my context :
DataReaders used respectively on the main thread and thread TH execute a select command for the same connection.
The SqlDataAdapter.Fill method probably uses an internal DataReader.
A try to execute the Fill method can be made on the main thread while another call to the Fill method is not yet finished on thread TH.